# What happens when Naruto is talking to the Kyuubi?

Tags: naruto

When Naruto is talking to the Kyuubi is his mind or his spirit inside the Kyuubi?

What happens while he is running? Does he have something like an autopilot?

Comment: Naruto's bit lucky not to have hit a tree trunk or a lamp post while on call with the Kyuubi.

Comment: I think when Naruto is talking to Kyuubi and running at the same time or doing something else, it's like when we are thinking of something but still conscious of what we are doing.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's like thinking while running, or making a phone call.

His mind is there, but he's also aware of his surroundings, he's not gazing into space.

Also, it's very likely that these interactions happen much faster than we see them (in the real world), just like thoughts and dreams are experienced by the brain in a flash, while to us it *seems* as if it took minutes (in reality it took less then a second).

Comment: In some cases Kurama and Naruto are talking in real time. I think the stuff they're doing in Naruto's mind while they are talking is just a representation as it would look a lot interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Its more like when we talk to our Inner selves when we are hitting on a girl.

```
Is she looking at Me ?

Why is she looking ?
```

When you first learn to ride bicycle you have to think a lot and then after sometime it becomes automatic.

Naruto does not have to make conscious effort to talk to Kyuubi, he can simultaneously talk to Kyuubi and do other stuff, because its automatic now.

Answer (score 1):

It may be like shadow clones. One of his shadow clone conscience talk to kuruma while other runs. When talk is done he simply undo jutsu and know his little conversation with kuruma.

During strong moments he cannot run and talk , since he had to concentrate all his chakra at one place.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Naruto is able to talk to the Kyuubi (Kurama) while not having to go inside his mind. He usually goes inside his mind when he really has to, wants to, or just needs power. But if hes not falling or standing still but he's actually running he wont really go into hi mind to see the Kyuubi or he will hit something. He would have to stop if he wants to actaully see the fox. That's why he can talk to the the Kyuubi or the Kyuubi talks to him without Naruto having to go inside his mind.

p.s: The nine tailed fox's name is Kurama.

Comment: I've fixed the grammar on your post, but it still needs some references or citations to justify your claims.