# How could time seem to be slowed down when a Host speaks with his Tailed Beast?

Tags: naruto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens when Naruto is talking to the Kyuubi?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/664/what-happens-when-naruto-is-talking-to-the-kyuubi)

Remember the scene, Jiraiya pushed Naruto off the cliff! or Naruto in tailed beast form when got stuck in Pain's Chibaku-tensai. They seem to have long time conversation among themselves isn't it?

How much time does it take to fall from a cliff to hit the ground… But Naruto and jinchuriki take their own time to come to an understanding.
Same thing goes while Naruto has conversation with Kyubi, Kushina and Minato for long time! it takes several minutes but in reality it wouldn't be more than few seconds.

How is the time managed?

Comment: I think this is a not a duplicate. This question is concerned with how time seems to slow down enough for them to have a conversation, while the other question does not seem to be concerned about time.

Comment: But the answer given in the other one covers the time-lapse part as well.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai: A "duplicate question" applies to answers as well. Since one of the answers (not just one, the accepted one) contains the answer to this question in its full, it should be closed as a duplicate to avoid content duplication.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I did not read the answer to the other question, but I read it now and you are right.

Comment: Yes the original post provided answer.. I just oversaw .. My bad .. I recommend to close it. If any admins around here.. please delete this q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than dismissing this as "artistic license", I'd rather see it as time passing differently in different dimensions, where "talking with the Kyuubi" takes place in a special dimension inside the Junchuuriki. For instance, in the [Tsukuyomi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tsukuyomi) technique,

> Itachi's prowess with the technique has allowed him to alter the perception of time with ease within the genjutsu to make a few seconds seem like many days as a means to torture the target.

Comment: agreeable points .. accepted ..

Comment: Thanks, but this is wishful thinking that would make sense, not really official information :)

Comment: Agreed, in case of Naruto and Kurama, this is the better explanation than artistic license. But artistic license does apply in a majority of cases, such as the Sakura's 3-minute antidote, Kakashi-Zabuza fight, etc.

Answer (score 6):

[Flexible time](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TalkingIsAFreeAction) is an [Artistic License](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArtisticLicense) taken by the creators, and is generally considered acceptable since it serves to narrate the story better, and this is quite common. Quoting TVTropes:

> Creators are allowed to be inaccurate if the inaccuracy serves the
>   story better than accuracy would.

This feels unusual for anime adapted from the manga. In the manga, the panels are not proportional to real life time. You can use more panels to describe some events in more detail compared to others, even though they may occupy the same amount of time. In the anime, however, the frame duration is proportional to real life time, but the narration should follow the manga, which leads to this anomaly.

In the examples you mentioned, if the anime creators had to keep the times realistic, they would not be able to convey the same detail that Kishimoto-sensei included in the manga, which would make for a poorer viewing experience.

To elaborate on that point, there is another example near the start of the series, when Naruto and Sasuke team up to rescue Kakashi from Zabuza's Water Prison. Naruto then spends about 5 minutes explaining what his plan was, while Kakashi and Zabuza wait! That is entirely impossible in a real battle, but without it, the viewers would have no way of knowing what happened, and it would not be interesting to watch.

Comment: Another example is during Sakura and Chiyo's fight with Sasori, when Sakura takes an anti-dote which should last for 3 minutes. They talk for 5 minutes and then fight for another 20 minutes or so, before they run out of those 3 minutes!

Comment: And they taunt saying `Deidara dosen't know art and artists!` ;) :P thank you ..